# How to skip values on particular indexes in Line Chart using MPAndroid Chart Library?

Tags: java, android, charts, mpandroidchart

I am using MPAndroid Chart Library for plotting Line Chart and I am setting dynamic data on LineChart but sometimes I am getting data as value 0.0 for some indexes and I don't want show 0.0 values on any index.
How can I skip indexes having 0.0 value.

```
ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
       entries.add(new Entry(23.00f, 0));
       entries.add(new Entry(40.00f, 1));
       entries.add(new Entry(00.00f, 2)); // want to skip this index 2(Mar)
       entries.add(new Entry(00.00f, 3)); // want to skip this index 3 (Apr)
       entries.add(new Entry(94.00f, 4));
       entries.add(new Entry(20.00f, 5));
```

Now i am getting like this 
[image]

But i would like to get some thing like this

[image]

Any Idea about this ?

Thanks

Comment: you can skip adding 0.0 to your graph

Comment: @Sree exactly what i have to do for skip this values ?

Comment: Did you find any solution? if yes, plz share. I am also stuck in same scenario.

Comment: @RahulParihar Yes some how it was done but need to find that code and will post it here shortly

Answer (score 2):

Finally after a lot of Internet search , i found solution.
I tried many solutions but in my case and best fit with question is as well.

Get the axis suppose we are planning to hide useless sequence value from the xAxix

```
xAxis.setLabelCount(originalValueArray.size, true)
```

where `originalValueArray` is the array of original data source.

Above solution will only draw required label and it will remove unnecessary sequence data.

Answer (score 1):

What about adding multiple dataset, one for each contiguous part of your graph ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try Override `drawData` method from `LineChartRender` and do this:

```
int index = lineData.getDataSets().size();
for (ILineDataSet set : lineData.getDataSets()) {            
                if (set.getEntryForIndex(index).getY() != 0) {
                    if (set.isVisible()) {
                        drawDataSet(c, set);
                    }
                }

        c.drawBitmap(mDrawBitmap.get(), 0, 0, mRenderPaint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be looking as:

```
ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
       entries.add(new Entry(23.00f, 0));
       entries.add(new Entry(40.00f, 1));
//       entries.add(new Entry(00.00f, 2)); // want to skip this index 2(Mar)
//       entries.add(new Entry(00.00f, 3)); // want to skip this index 3 (Apr)
       entries.add(new Entry(94.00f, 4));
       entries.add(new Entry(20.00f, 5));
```

The lib will draw it automatically as on screenshot 2.

Comment: It does not work man. I tried this before posting my question here.

Comment: I have similar task and not adding data works for me. The other option is to have the Array list of colors for the points and make the the 00,00f entries color transparent. And change it after that to the new value, calculated to